# How can I get all new versions of a packages since last time checking?

Tags: apt, package-management, deb

I need to build a CI pipeline that will build my own package against all versions of another package. Therefore I need to track the version changes.

Is there a convenient way to achieve this, e.g. I can download packages.gz regularly and compare it with an old one to find out all the new versions.

Thanks

Comment: That's one good way. Or you can track updates using the madison database (try `apt-cache-madison <package_name>`. Or you can scrape http://packages.ubuntu.com. Or you can learn about changes using your history log (`/var/log/apt/history.log`). Or you can scrape the package's page on launchpad.net. Or you can look for an updated changelog at http://changelogs.ubuntu.com. Pick whatever is "convenient" for you.

Comment: @user535733 thank you for your quick response. I tried apt-cache-madison, but I am a little bit confused. What I run actually was `apt-cache madison linux-headers-generic`, it returned way less results (actually only 2) than `apt-cache search linux-headers | grep generic`. I don't understand why so many linux-headers-x.x.x-xx-generic packages don't match `linux-headers-generic`